# Conditional rendering according to props

Tags: reactjs

I am passing "winners" as a prop to my PastWinner component. How can I conditionally render my winner component if and only if my `{winner.baseId}`
is greater than my `currentRound` (variable from the context)?

This is my current code

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { CanContext } from '../context/canContext';

const PastWinner = ({ winner }) => {
  const { currentRound } = useContext(CanContext);
  return (
    <>
      <td className='px-4 py-2'>{winner.baseId}</td>
      <td className='px-4 py-2'>{winner.respondee}</td>
    </>
  );
};
export default PastWinner;
```

I tried to do something like this but it dosen't work

```
return (
  {winner.baseId > currentRound ? (
    <>
    <td className='px-4 py-2'>{winner.baseId}</td>
    <td className='px-4 py-2'>{winner.respondee}</td>
  </>
  ): (<></>)}
)
```

The result of the winner object is as below:

```
{
baseId: "0"
originalResponse: "great"
respondee: "0x9d95bcaa5b609fa97a7ec860bec115aa94f85ba9"
submittedAt: "2022-06-01T05:24:03.218Z"
voters: ['0x39c878a3df98002ddba477a7aa0609fb5a27e2ff']
votes: 1
__v: 0
_id: "6296f7f3fe1858980b69dd2f"
}
```

Comment: are you sure about currentRounded value and winners.baseId ?
you can check with console.log() if neither of them is undefiend and condition is as it expected

Comment: What you did should work in theory. That's how we usually do conditional rendering in React. Like @AliSattarzadeh mentioned, it might be an issue with your variables.

Comment: Can you post the structure of the `winner` object?

Comment: hmm the variables both work @AliSattarzadeh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the question, I just have to wrap everything in a <></>

```
return (
<>
  {winner.baseId > currentRound ? (
    <>
    <td className='px-4 py-2'>{winner.baseId}</td>
    <td className='px-4 py-2'>{winner.respondee}</td>
  </>
  ): (<></>)}
</>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the contents of your `winner` object, the property `baseId` seems to be of type `string`.

You should not compare values of different types in such a way.

So this will not necessarily resolve your issue, due to the way comparisons work in JS.
But it may point to a different problem. Not to mention that it is simply incorrect..

There are 3 main methods of parsing to an integer in JS.

1. Adding a `+` before the variable name when referring to it:

```
return (
  {+winner.baseId > currentRound && (
    <>
      <td className='px-4 py-2'>{winner.baseId}</td>
      <td className='px-4 py-2'>{winner.respondee}</td>
    </>
  )}
)
```

2. Using the [`Number`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp) method:

```
return (
  {Number(winner.baseId) > currentRound && (
    <>
      <td className='px-4 py-2'>{winner.baseId}</td>
      <td className='px-4 py-2'>{winner.respondee}</td>
    </>
  )}
)
```

3. Using the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function.

```
return (
  {parseInt(winner.baseId, 10) > currentRound && (
    <>
      <td className='px-4 py-2'>{winner.baseId}</td>
      <td className='px-4 py-2'>{winner.respondee}</td>
    </>
  )}
)
```

I recommend using `parseInt`.

**Note:** The second parameter of `parseInt` represents the radix/base value.
It is not optional and must be added.

**P.S.** make sure that `currentRound` is a number as well.

Comment: Yes that seems to be one of the problems, thanks. But I still get a swiggly over the . in parseInt(winner.baseId, 10) because it says ", expected"

Comment: Strange, should be very simple. https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-jh5o6e?file=/index.js

Comment: Did this work out or are you still facing issues? @xxavierxx

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
  if(winner?.baseId > currentRound){
    return (<>
      <td className='px-4 py-2'>{winner?.baseId}</td>
      <td className='px-4 py-2'>{winner?.respondee}</td>
    </>)
  }else{
    return <></>
  }
```